# can't delete folders listed in file

Tags: linux, centos

I can't delete folders with content listed in a file using this script (clean_folders.sh) that seem to be correct :

```
while read -r path; do
    echo "deleting $path"
    rm -rf "$path"
done </home/opm/Downloads/fw/DEV_validation_run_to_test.txt
```

no error when i use -f but when i remove it i get this messege :

```
rm: cannot remove '/home/opm/Desktop/de/1/11.parquet'$'\r': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/home/opm/Desktop/de/2/22.parquet'$'\r': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/home/opm/Desktop/de/3/33.parquet'$'\r': No such file or directory
```

OS: Centos

Thanks for help,

Comment: Two little questions :  1) could you check that encoding WIndows/Linux is ok for you file ( /home/opm/Downloads/fw/DEV_validation_run_to_test.txt )? May be a little dos2unix is necessary ?

2) I have an impression that directory has some special chars in their names, like ' $ \ etc Could you confirm ?

Comment: `$'\r'` - your input file has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: yes it was dos2unix problem, this command fix the issue : perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' input
thanks @PaulZakharov ,  KamilCuk